# Deep Learning: Is validation dataset used in training?

Tags: deep-learning

In supervised learning, original data is divided three part: training dataset, validation dataset and test dataset.

The training dataset is used to train a model.

The test dataset is used to evaluate the model finally, so is not used in training process.

The validation dataset is used for tuning parameters of the model while training, I think.

What I want to know is whether the validation dataset is used for training or not. Is it used for calculating weights and bias?

Comment: Hi, yes it is, it validates your parameters. This is not really the place to ask a "text book" type question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as you said you use validation data for hyperparameter tuning. One more use of validation data is that it is used to check if you are overfitting on the training data

Comment: In my opinion, validation dataset is used for tuning of parameters. And test dataset is used for tuning of hyperparameters.

Answer (score 0):

In supervised learning, the validation dataset is used during the training phase, but not in the same way the training dataset is used.

Since the goal is to get a model that can predict/classify new instances with high precision and/or accuracy, it's very important to minimize the error.

Thus, the training dataset is used to calculate the weights and biases of the neuronal network. And the validation dataset is used to calculate the error and adjust the weights/biases for the next training epoch. This is done by using the validation dataset instances to predict the label, compare it with the actual and calculate the precision.

Hope this helps you clarify this topic. You can also refer to some textbooks.

Comment: So you mean that the validation dataset is not used for calculating weights and bias and used only for evaluating trained model at every epoch. Right?

Comment: @Tienn you're rigth